# Notepad++ Is there a way to fold function header documentation?

Tags: r, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to edit R files.  I can fold a function, but can't figure out how to fold the function header (i.e. all consecutive lines of comments above a function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a good way to do this.  Marking this as an answer until a better one appears =)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the function header in curly braces should do it.

E.g

{
your comments
}

Comment: @SFun28 OK, never had to compile in R, I just use source(). However you could try placing the comments after the function statement and wrap them up inside the function. e.g. f <- function(x) { # comments

Comment: thanks for the suggestions...unfortunately this won't work because the comment block must be above the function.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at NpptoR (notepad++ to R) at http://sourceforge.net/projects/npptor/

Multiple lines can be commented by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Comment: I'm looking for fold/collapse of comments, not multi-line commenting...unless I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Chris answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431224/notepad-is-there-a-way-to-fold-function-header-documentation/6432742#6432742) did you try following:

```
{# This is first line

# My dummy function
f <- function(x) {
    y <- 1
    sin(x+y)
}
}
```

which wrap function with comments, or:

```
{# This is first line

# My dummy function
}
f <- function(x) {
    y <- 1
    sin(x+y)
}
```

In my Notepad++ it looks like this:

[image: Folding comments]

Comment: thanks for the suggestions...unfortunately these don't work in conjunction with R's popular Roxygen documentation package (which generates documentation from function header comments).  I might be out of luck.